# Select latest record if duplicate oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table save sending & receiving process as example

| id | sender | receiver |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | A |
| 2 | A | B |
| 3 | A | C |
| 4 | B | D |
| 5 | D | B |
| 6 | B | D |

But i don't know how to write oracle query to select the latest with unique receiver. Expected result as:

| id | sender | receiver |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | A |
| 3 | A | C |
| 5 | D | B |
| 6 | B | D |

Any ideas on how I can accomplish the result i'm after?

Comment: I don't understand the logic behind your expected output.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it's like a workflow. I wan't to select the latest records with unique recevier. Because record id 2 & 5 same receiver B, so i want to select the latest is record id 5. Similar record id 4 & 6. Receiver A & C has only one, so selected them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `ROW_NUMBER()` here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY receiver ORDER BY id DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable t
)

SELECT id, sender, receiver
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY id;
```